# EPUB files are not syncing through iCloud for iBooks along with iOS 9.3

Tags: icloud, ios, ibook

Since 21 March 2016, I am able to sync any books via icloud between devices. It works pretty good for pdf. But it doesnt work for **EPUB** files. I have downloaded for my iPhone some **EPUB** file from the website and saved to iBooks, but it didn't appear on my another device, while the pdf did appear.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS iBooks try tapping the "Collections" selector top center of the app below the system time and turning OFF "Hide iCloud Books".

Comment: Amazing, it really works:)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I actually did the OPPOSITE and it worked -- Turned ON "Hide iCloud Books" and restarted the app and suddenly everything was synced up.